# JQuery not working in aspx page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am working with some jQuery to change a cell in a table, for some reason I can't understand why it's not working. I thought because of how the jquery code is it does not need to be binded, Am I wrong?

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    var i = 0, tds = td.length;
    for (i; i < tds; i++) {
        if (td[i].innerText == 75) {
            td[i].setAttribute("style", "background:green;");
        }
    }

</script>
```

Update:
Here is what i have in the head of the aspx page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var td = $("td");
    var i = 0, tds = td.length;
    for (i; i < tds; i++) {
        td[i].setAttribute("style", "background:green;");
         if (td[i].innerText == 75) {
            td[i].setAttribute("style", "background:green;");
        }
    } 

</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/JavaScript1.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/StyleSheet1.css" />
<title id="FttTitle" runat="server"></title>
</head>
```

And here is the table that is being rendered:

```
 <div id="DataList1" style="color: white" align="center" runat="server">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" Style="color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size:18px;">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table id="ptbl" runat="server" cellpadding="2" border="1" style="color: white; font-weight: bold; font-size:18px;">
                    <tr runat="server">
                        <th runat="server">Team Name</th>
                        <th runat="server">Points</th>
                        <th runat="server">Wins</th>
                        <th runat="server">Loss</th>
                        <th runat="server">Ties</th>
                        <th runat="server">Win %</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                </table>
                <asp:DataPager runat="server" ID="ContactsDataPager" PageSize="90">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ShowFirstPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="true"
                            FirstPageText="|&lt;&lt; " LastPageText=" &gt;&gt;|"
                            NextPageText=" &gt; " PreviousPageText=" &lt; " />
                    </Fields>
                </asp:DataPager>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr runat="server">

                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Style="font-weight: bold"><%# Eval("Tm_Nm") %></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Style="font-weight: bold"><%# Eval("TP") %></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Style="font-weight: bold"><%# Eval("W") %></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Style="font-weight: bold"><%# Eval("L") %></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Style="font-weight: bold"><%# Eval("T") %></asp:Label></td>
                    <td id="TLD">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Style="font-weight: bold"><%# Eval("TL")%></asp:Label></td>
                    <td><span id="MainContent_Label2">75</span></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't see that you're using any jQuery in that script.

Comment: @Difster - That code in the second script tag isn't jquery?

Comment: No, that's just regular JavaScript.
jQuery would be: `var td = $("td");`

Comment: Difster is right: you are not using jQuery. You can try `if (td[i].innerText === "75") { td[i].style.backgroundColor = "green"; }` to set the background color of the cell (in plain Javascript).

Comment: Tested your code locally and it's working

Comment: @kblok i did not, is there something i need to add to the td tag in the html? or is it because i am using chrome?

Comment: could you try with plain HTML in your page? <table><tr><td>75</td></tr></table>

Comment: @kblok - not quite

Comment: I have the place where the cell should change like this: <td id="TLD">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Style="font-weight: bold"><%# Eval("TL")%></asp:Label></td>

Comment: Yup man, that's working for me, could you post the html being rendered?

Comment: it would be better if you provide the sample html generated along with the question.

Comment: Please check weather you have placed this script after you table is rendered? Or it will be better to write this code in document ready function.

Answer (score -1):

jquery method

```js
$(function() {
  var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  var i = 0,
    tds = td.length;
  for (i; i < tds; i++) {
    if (td[i].innerText == 75) {
      td[i].setAttribute("style", "background:green;");
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="MainContent_Label1">80</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><span id="MainContent_Label2">75</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

or equivalent pure javascript method;

```js
(function() {
  var td = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
  var i = 0,
    tds = td.length;
  for (i; i < tds; i++) {
    if (td[i].innerText == 75) {
      td[i].setAttribute("style", "background:green;");
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span id="MainContent_Label1">80</span></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><span id="MainContent_Label2">75</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Here is what i have in the head section of the aspx page

Comment: I added more code to help explain what is going on.

Comment: I put the script script in a js file and included it, but that did not work

Comment: Hope you have moved your js code to JavaScript1.js file. But still in the example I can see the js code inside the script tag also. Its a bit confusing. Also the important part is that this code should be rendered only after complete rendering of your table and its content. Either you should call your js file after the rendering of table(inside body itself). But it is always better to use a document ready function as i have shown with this answer.